# How can this implication be proved?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

What I have given is:

(i) $\operatorname{f}(a_{n})\leq0$ and $\operatorname{f}(b_{n})\geq0.$

(ii)$\forall n\in\Bbb N_{0}: a\leq a_{n}\leq a_{n+1}\leq b_{n+1}\leq b_{n}\leq b.$

(iii)$\forall n \in \Bbb N_{0}:b_{n}-a_{n}=\frac{b-a}{2^{n}}.$

Now it is stated $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ are bounded monotone increasing/decreasing sequences. The bounds are 0 for $a_{n}$ and $b_{0}$ for $b_{n}$, right?

I understood (if my reasoning for why both sequences are bounded is correct) everything so far.

What I understand only partly is:

$\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}a_{n} = \lim \limits_{n\to\infty}b_{n}$

I understand that $b_{n}-a_{n}$ is a null sequence.

But which theorem is used to state:

$\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}a_{n} = \lim \limits_{n\to\infty}b_{n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are both monotone bounded sequences. Hence they have finite limits. Also $\lim b_n-\lim a_n=\lim (b_n-a_n) =\lim \frac {b-a} {2^{n}}=0$. Hence $\lim b_n=\lim a_n$

Comment: Okay I seem to understand. So $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}b_{n}=\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}a_{n}$ because when you subtract $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}a_{n}$ from $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}b_{n}$ the result has to be $0$ which only happens if $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}b_{n}=\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}a_{n}$ . Is that reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. @MathNoob